# How do I force an android gradle build to fail if I'm missing translations

Tags: android, gradle

I am trying to get gradle to fail my android build if I miss a string that has not been translated in my spanish `strings.xml` file and haven't had any luck. I'm aware that there are IDE level options in Android studio but, I was hoping there was some gradle configuration or flag I could set to make my build fail. I've tried adding a couple of flags to my gradle file under lint options but they haven't really done anything.

```
lintOptions {
    abortOnError true
    quiet true
    ignoreWarnings false
    enable 'MissingTranslation'
}
```

Never asked a question on here before so I apologize if I haven't asked properly

**update**

Seems like adding a flag to the lint block allowed our build to fail on our build machine.

```
lintOptions {
    abortOnError true
    ignoreWarnings true
    fatal 'MissingTranslation'
}
```

Having our machine run ./gradlew assembleRelease caught our untranslated strings and failed our build. Hope this helps someone else!

Comment: are you creating a release .apk file?

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable missing translations with:

```
disable 'MissingTranslation'
```

Check this configuration:

```
 lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        disable 'MissingTranslation'
        abortOnError false
    }
```

Comment: This is just hiding the error not solving it. I do not judge the solution but since I wouldnt like to forget that I have missing translations I would use the resConfig in the BuildTypes

Comment: You want to add all the translations? For me translations are not required my app is only in english language.

Comment: when lint warns you for something like this you have more than 1 language for your app. Ok maybe they are not required for you but if in the future you want to see for which languages you are missing translations maybe you will forget that you added this disable 'MissingTranslation'

Comment: Wouldn't that prevent gradle from complaining about missing translations? I was hoping for gradle to fail my build if it did find any missing translations.